# Click on a datagrid column header impossible

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I created a datagrid with dataGridTemplateColumn and I can't use the click on header to sort anymore. Here is a sample of my code :

```
       <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="action id" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding id}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Do you have an idea of what is going wrong? Is this because of the use of a template that the default sort is desactivated?

Thanks,

J.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should set the SortMemberPath property

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="id" Header="action id" Width="Auto">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the property `CanUserSortColumn = true` for your DataGridTemplateColumn.

Comment: That doesn't change anything :/

Comment: <DataGrid Name="grid_Actions" CanUserSortColumns="True" SelectionUnit="Cell" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="15" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >

Here is the xaml initialisation. Then in my code behind I just bind an ObservableClollection to the ItemsSource.